# How to add react.js to spring mvc application

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application (jsp as a views) and i want to add react.js as a frontend. I have a couple of questions: 
1. Where i should place my create-react-app folder or it doesn't matter. 
2. Is there a way to run the application from maven (war) only. I mean that i know only one way to run application it is start backend from maven and start react.js from npm start. But this approach requires to use proxy or cors (or i'm wrong). I am using IntellijI IDEA and WebStorm.

[project structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSvrO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It doesn't matter
2. You are right that you should run it on different servers for spring and react.
3. You can proxy your api request to the backend to avoid CORS issue.

Copy this to your `src/setupProxy.js` in your create-react-app. More info [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = app => {
  app.use(
    proxy("/api", {
      target: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
      pathRewrite: { "^/api": "" },
      changeOrigin: true
    })
  );
};
```

Then you can proxy request to your backend using `/api` prefix. Example i can do something like `fetch('/api/users')` in my frontend react app

Comment: "You are right that you should run it on different servers for spring and react."
As i understand there is no way to run they together?
Maybe there is some feature that can do it?

Comment: of course there is. in development i suggest going into this approach for productivity purposes because webpack-dev-server is great for development. for production, you can serve your build folder from your spring web server as static files.

Comment: tnak you for answer)